# Request header field X-CSRF-Token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response for Drupal 7 REST API

Tags: 7, services, csrf

I have few APIs created in Drupal 7 which uses session authentication. Now when I get the CSRF token and try to use it in my API call, I get following error:
**Request header field X-CSRF-Token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

Here is my javascript code:

```
var url = "http://dev/api/v1/macc/*";
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
// xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
// xhttp.setRequestHeader('cookie', cookie);

xhttp.send();
```

If I run the same API from Advanced Rest Client, I get the correct response.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [cors module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cors)
You'll be able to add necessary Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Otherwise, you can do this by changing your apache (or nginx or whatever) conf.

In drupal 8, you define this in services.yml, as explain [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637).